# Disable Slider Swipe on Mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, flexslider

I have a Wordpress theme in which I have a slider set with only 1 picture & the slider is automatically creating a cloned slide before & after the slide I'm actually using, which technically results in 3 slides instead of only the 1 I created. This isn't a problem on the desktop site, however on the mobile version it is allowing swipe to left or right to see the next "slide".

I have limited knowledge of php, and have tried many different changes, but I can't get anything to work. The most I have accomplished is that now it is not showing the picture, just a dark "slide". I have researched extensively the past 2 days and I think I have overloaded myself.

I believe the best option would be if I can prevent the slider from creating the 2 cloned slides before and after the slide I want to use, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any direction would be greatly appreciated as I'm exhausting myself!

Comment: Can't really help you without any code or documentation to look at. Is this slider part of the theme or a plugin?

Comment: It's part of the theme. Sorry, I didn't know if it was something someone would know without the code or not. I'm using the Eleganto Theme and I can post the code, just not 100% sure which file I might need to post.

Comment: Is there any documentation included with the theme? Usually plugins like sliders will have options that you can add in to customize the slider. For example, `scrollOnMobile: 'True'` would mean it allowed scrolling and having to set to "False" would prevent scrolling. But the theme might be different.

Comment: The theme only has support & info if you purchase the pro theme. I have looked through their slider.php file, but there is nothing like this, so the only spot I can think to find this would be within the jquery flexslider file, so in this instance is it acceptable to change that file or would it be a better idea to create a child file? Here's the code for the slider.php file from the theme  https://jsfiddle.net/znv3z4L8/

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be acceptable to change it. I'm just unsure on what to change to prevent the scrolling.

Comment: I finally found a way to fix my issue. I found where I can change the animationLoop to not loop through the slides on the jquery flexslider. Not the fix I necessarily wanted, but it will work for now.

Comment: Awesome! Good on you for sticking to it.